# Why is a flashback more appropriate than a resistance roll in this case?

Tags: forged-in-the-dark, scum-and-villainy, flashback, resistance-roll

My rules of thumb for flashbacks vs resistance rolls in *FITD* have always been:

- If the player is attempting to contradict something the GM just said ("No, that doesn't happen, because…"), it's almost certainly a resistance roll.
- If they want their character to have done something in the past that *doesn't* contradict anything the GM has narrated so far, it's probably a flashback.
- If they're trying to prevent something bad from happening, it's more likely to be a resistance roll.

But then I came across this example from the *Scum and Villainy* rulebook, discussing uses of the Attune action:

> Rogan’s crew has smuggled a Guild scientist to some Suneaters
> on Indri. They’re about to cash in when the Urbot by the Suneaters
> twitches, grabs a gun, and opens fire. “Not so fast!” says Rogan’s
> player. “I can sense killing intent by attuning to the Way. Flash
> back to a few seconds earlier where I frown, look around, and yell
> ‘Look out!’ before the robot fires.” “Cool, sounds like a 0 stress
> flashback since you folks are a bit nervous about this handoff in
> the first place. It’s a risky roll, where the risk is you paint yourself
> as the first target for that killer Urbot when you yell.”

Why is this a flashback instead of resistance roll?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Take the [tour]! I understand completely the desire to explain why you have the question in the first place (i.e. "Answers I have considered and rejected…"), but doing so this way tends to limit artificially the answers you receive. In short, consider deleting that section and letting the answers—and the users who vote on those answers—do the work of rejecting them. You may be surprised. (And you'll be able to comment on those answers if you find them faulty when restated, too.) This is in no way required, by the way! That said, thank you for participating and have fun!

Comment: I took the liberty of removing that section for you. I hope that's okay. You're free to rollback to the previous version of your question. You'll also note that I changed the wording to omit speculation about authorial intent. The site struggles with questions like that. Again, please edit further or rollback if the question doesn't match your vision.

Comment: @HeyICanChan, thanks for the tip! That makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The flashback doesn’t change any stated actions, only affects their outcomes

As other answers state, the distinction between resistance and flashback isn’t always clear cut, but this example makes sense to me. Key to this is stated intent vs outcome, but also who and what is being affected.

While we don’t have the verbatim text of the GM’s narration, from context they seem to have quickly stated three actions for the Urbot: it glitches, grabs a gun and opens fire. But who it fires at, and whether it hits anyone, are importantly *not yet established*.

Rogan’s player is having him use the Way to “sense killing intent”, so they have to be accepting the bot’s actions and intent as established so far. What they are changing are things outside of the GM’s narration: their own character’s actions, and information being given to the rest of the room.

There’s no contradiction if the bot fires at what is now empty air, as everyone’s hit the deck, or if it targets Rogan instead of the other people present.

As a cinematic metaphor, we can think about this in two ways. In either scenario, we’ve been watching a shot of the bot glitching and grabbing the gun, and then turning and firing.

The flashback could be read as editing the scene to insert a closeup of Rogan’s face frowning as the bot glitches, then another turning towards it and shouting “look out!” as it grabs the gun and then fires. Or perhaps the whole scene of the Urbot rewinds and we realise this is a flash of the future sensed by Rogan, who shouts a warning just as the scene plays out again, only now everyone isn’t taken by surprise (something the GM, importantly, hasn’t stated has happened).

Either way, Rogan’s actions are new additions to the scene which don’t contradict the existing narrative, but obviously will affect what happens next. In that respect they’re just like a more traditional flashback which goes back much further in time.

As to why it’s more appropriate - it suits the player’s stated action and justification better!

Answer (score 4):

### In this case, either one was appropriate enough.

> The rules don't distinguish between actions performed in the present and those performed in the past.
>
> -- Scum and Villainy, "Flashbacks", p.156

There is some overlap for the affectable narrative scope here, just like there almost always is. Aside from engagement at the top and heat at the bottom, there isn't any prescribed order of action rolls to take to complete a score. Players do what makes sense to them in the moment and the GM spins clocks and deals consequences as appropriate.

In this situation, could someone also make a Resolve resistance roll to lay down a social smoke screen in the moment, stopping the "Sudden But Inevitable Betrayal" clock (which has totally always been a thing) at 2 or 3 out of 4? Yeah, I'd accept that if someone pitched it to me.

However, there are situations where one is definitely much more appropriate than the other.

#### Flashbacks require a plausible action in the past. Resistance is always possible in the present.

> Theron Red -- one of the fiercest bounty hunters the Scarlet Wolves have to offer [-- is] standing up and kicking a sofa between you to block your sight, and heavy blaster fire comes tearing through it and the doorway as he wastes no time. Would you like to resist the damage?
>
> -- Scum and Villainy, "NPC Threat Levels", p.204

In this case, when the entire point is that an NPC is a tier above you and can turn violence on you before you can react, the Attune flashback definitely wouldn't be appropriate. Theron Red doesn't spend a long time planning violence, he's just got really well-trained reflexes. Could you use a flashback to armor spaceport sofa 45B, specifically? Somehow sabotage a top-flight bounty hunter's blaster or ammo without him ever noticing?

Sometimes, flashbacks are just too implausible, but a resistance roll is always an option.

#### Resistance blunts the severity of something to you in the present. Flashbacks change the meaning of something for everyone from the past.

> [I]f you got a complication when you were sneaking into the manor house, and the GM was going to mark three ticks on the "Alert" clock, she'd only mark two (or maybe one) if you resisted the complication.
>
> -- Scum and Villainy, "Resistance & Armor", p.35

But let's suppose you're at 7 out of 8 ticks on that "Alert" clock, and you completely honk a desperate roll. The GM isn't obliged to let you stop that "Alert" clock from filling up. There are also some cases where the GM isn't acting on you specifically, such as when an engagement roll goes badly and the entire crew starts out in a bad position. No one crew member, or even all of them together, can make a resistance roll to prevent that.

But, while a flashback can never outright contradict the events of the present, they can change what it means when, say, the "Alert" clock fills up. Flashback to last night when you were up a utility pole rewiring the alarm grid so that when the alert fires the Imperials head off on a wild goose chase? Yeah, alright, you can buy 4 segments on this "misdirection" clock with a risky Tinker roll or 6 segments with a desperate one, but they'll be actively investigating to correct their mistake so it'll bleed time no matter what you do.

#### When something can be represented both as a reducible consequence and a plot element someone could have foreseen, either are appropriate.

And we loop back to the start.

If as a GM I'm willing to frame the urbot firing as the consequence of a clock filling, someone can try to resist that, risking a stress cost to delay it and buying time for someone else to act.

Or, someone can use a flashback to change what happens when that clock fills; rather than the urbot opening fire on a bunch of unsuspecting targets (almost certainly dealing harm directly) it opens fire on people who have dived for cover, pinning them down but not harming anyone.

Note that a player flashback almost always contradicts something the GM was planning to happen - there's a little room for the GM to judge that it contradicts too much of the setup to be workable. Diving for cover in the moment fits the setup much better than, say, sneaking into the suneater ship the night before and jetissoning the urbot into space.

Comment: I appreciate the other examples you bring in, but I don't understand how this applies to the scenario at hand. We both agree that a flashback can never outright contradict the events of the present. Here, the GM says "the Urbot fires" and the player says "Not so fast!". Does that not mean they're attempting to contradict the narration?

Comment: I've tweaked the final section; hope it helps a little there.